# How invoke state machine from aws cloud watch event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-events-rule.html) is example for lambda invocation by event:

```
EventRule: 
  Type: AWS::Events::Rule
  Properties: 
    Description: "EventRule"
    EventPattern: 
      source: 
        - "aws.ec2"
      detail-type: 
        - "EC2 Instance State-change Notification"
      detail: 
        state: 
          - "stopping"
    State: "ENABLED"
    Targets: 
      - 
        Arn: 
          Fn::GetAtt: 
            - "LambdaFunction"
            - "Arn"
        Id: "TargetFunctionV1"
PermissionForEventsToInvokeLambda: 
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties: 
    FunctionName: 
      Ref: "LambdaFunction"
    Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    Principal: "events.amazonaws.com"
    SourceArn: 
      Fn::GetAtt: 
        - "EventRule"
        - "Arn"
```

How to modify this tp be able to invoke state machine not lambda? I have replaced `"LambdaFunction` with `"MyStateMachine"`
but how modify `PermissionForEventsToInvokeLambda`? There is no `AWS::StepFunctions::Permission` in cloudformation :-(

Answer (score 0):

Here's an snippet from the template we *used* to have to trigger state machine processing from an S3 event:

```
  InboundBucketPutObjectRule:
    Type: 'AWS::Events::Rule'
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub 'inbound-bucket-put-object-rule'
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - aws.s3
        detail-type:
          - AWS API Call via CloudTrail
        detail:
          eventSource:
            - s3.amazonaws.com
          eventName:
            - PutObject
            - CopyObject
            - CompleteMultipartUpload
          requestParameters:
            bucketName:
              - !Ref InboundBucket
      Targets:
        - Id: ProcessNewObject
          Arn: !Ref StateMachine
          RoleArn: !GetAtt 
            - StateMachineStartExecutionRole
            - Arn
  StateMachineStartExecutionPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy'
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyName: !Sub 'state-machine-start-execution'
      Roles:
        - !Ref StateMachineStartExecutionRole
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'states:StartExecution'
            Resource:
              - !Ref StateMachine
  StateMachineStartExecutionRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub 'state-machine-start-execution'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: events.amazonaws.com
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
  StateMachine:
    Type: 'AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine'
    Properties:
      StateMachineName: !Sub 'state-machine'
```

Taken from real template so I had to anonymize this which might have introduced errors.

Template structure:

- `InboundBucketPutObjectRule` is the CloudWatch event which gets triggered on file uploads.
- `StateMachineStartExecutionPolicy` + `StateMachineStartExecutionRole` essentially allow CloudWatch event to start execution of a state machine.
- `StateMachine` - the state machine which should be started (definition omitted).

I wrote above that we *used* to have this - but not anymore. Please see the following answer for our current solution:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/57563395/303810